# ng-show, toggle right element on click [Angularjs]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I wana toggle elements but not all elements i need just one on which is clicked.

for example if I have 3 form elements and 3 buttons if I click on button 1. I just wana toggle 1. form element.

This is my current code:

angular:

```
$scope.formWhat = false;
$scope.formShow = function(item){
                   $scope.formWhat = !$scope.formWhat;
               };
```

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in comments">
<a href="#" ng-click="formShow(x)">replay</a>
       <form id="<%x.id%>" ng-show="formWhat">
        blbllblblbl
        </form>
</div>
```

This code will open all forms, but i need just on which is clicked, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the helpful things here is that `ng-repeat` creates a child scope for each item repeated.

So you can use a local variable inside that child scope that controller knows nothing about. This won't close any of the others but that could be accomplished also. Criteria you gave wasn't very specific

```
<div ng-repeat="x in comments">
    <a ng-click="showForm = !showForm">replay</a>
    <form ng-show="showForm"></form>
</div>
```